# knockoutjs Binding Handler only firing when ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); is in update: part

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have two identical Binding Handlers and one of them is not firing, because it has no ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); in the "update:" part of it.

Best way to see what is going on, is to look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgav467w/). By hitting the button the first span toggles the background, but the second not.
When you uncomment line 26 "ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());" the 2nd update function is called and the other span toggles gray/white.

**HTML:**

```
<button id='ChangeValue'>item++</button>
<hr/>
<span>Update fired viewModel.item = </span>
<span data-bind='text: $data.item(), bind1: $data.item'></span>
<br/>
<span>Update not fired viewModel.item = </span>
<span data-bind='text: $data.item(), bind2: $data.item'></span>
```

**JS/jQuery/knockoutjs:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ChangeValue').click(function() {
        viewModel.item(viewModel.item() + 1);
    });    
    var viewModel = {
        item: ko.observable(1)
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.bind1 = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if (element.style.background == "gray") {
                element.style.background = "white";
            } else {
                element.style.background = "gray";
            }
        } 
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.bind2 = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            // if uncomment following line  "update" is called
            //ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if (element.style.background == "gray") {
                element.style.background = "white";
            } else {
                element.style.background = "gray";
            }
        } 
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Is this the expected behavior? I have a complex update functionality in my real code and was wondering why some of my binding handlers are not firing and after a long time of research I did extract this example.

I think it has something to do with the garbage collector in the browser (tested in chrome/IE 11) or knockout.

**So my questions:**

1. Is it enought to add "ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());" in my update part of the custom binding to be sure it will be processed?
2. Is there any documentation about that? Because I did not find something at [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is the expected behavior. The `update` method is called whenever the binding is applied, and while executing, knockout registers/tracks the `observables` that are accessed in update method. So in your case, the `bind2` binding is not accessing the valueAccessor value, therefore not triggering any update. So if you have

   ```
   var value = valueAccessor();
   var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
   ```

   This enables knockout to trigger `update` on any change in `valueAccessor()` observable.

   If you access the value of any `observable` in `update` function, the change in that observable will trigger the `update` function.
2. It is documented well [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Comment: Thanks Dandy, this was exactly what I was looking for. Now the behaviour makes sence to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Using: http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.1.0.js

http://jsfiddle.net/fgav467w/1/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bind1 = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (element.style.background == "gray") {
            element.style.background = "white";
        } else {
            element.style.background = "gray";
        }
    } 
};
```

The 3.0.0 releases removed a lot of extra "work" which Dandy describes. The 2.0.0 releases like the one I use in the fiddle did not. They will work as you intend but the overall performance will not be as good. But you have options at least.

Comment: Good point and thank's for the updated example! But I think I will stick with 3.3.0 :)